# haproxy port mapping backup server

Tags: haproxy

i have a small question regarding port forwarding in haproxy. I have a total of 2 servers. Once Server01 and Server02 as backup if Server01 fails. I have a port on Server01 which I have to reach via haproxy Port 8081 how can haproxy reach the port someone can tell me the setting in the config ?

The problem should Server01 fail should the same port on Server02 be reached by haproxy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check this port and setup the second server is a backup.

Try it (in backend construction):

```
    server Server01 10.10.10.11:8081 check port 8081
    server Server02 10.10.10.12:8081 backup check port 8081
```

---

My example:

```
backend appservers
    balance leastconn
    server Server01 10.10.10.11:8081 check port 8081 inter 3s fastinter 1s downinter 3s fall 2 rise 2
    server Server02 10.10.10.12:8081 backup weight 1 check port 8081 inter 3s fastinter 1s downinter 3s fall 2 rise 2
    server Server03 10.10.10.13:8081 backup weight 2 check port 8081 inter 3s fastinter 1s downinter 3s fall 2 rise 2
```